# C# what does ^= do?

Tags: c#, operands

I have been analyzing a source code but i am stuck trying to understand 
what this two do together `^=` in this evaluation:

```
array[i] ^= 5;
```

what does the `^=` operand stand for? 
is it doing this?:

```
array[i] = array[i] ^ 5;
```

thank you..

Comment: Yes, that's what it means

Comment: i dont understand, wasnt ^ supposed to be a comparison operator? like `(true ^ false)` would return true and `(true ^ true)` would return false? how does an `array[i] ^ 5` work? `5`cant be considered a boolean here :s

Comment: ^ is the bitwise XOR operator. It works on both booleans and integers. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/zkacc7k1.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a [compound assignment operator](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/expressions.md#compound-assignment). Compound assignment operators have the form

```
ω=
```

where `ω` is a binary operator. A compound assignment

```
a ω= b
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
a = a ω b
```

except that `a` is only evaluated once.

So, in your case

```
array[i] ^= 5
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
array[i] = array[i] ^ 5
```

but with the guarantee that `array[i]` is evaluated only once:

```
using System.Console;

class MainClass
{
    static int[] A() { Write("A"); return new int[] { 23 }; }
    static int   B() { Write("B"); return 0; }
    static int   C() { Write("C"); return 42; }

    public static void Main()
    {
        WriteLine("Compound Assignment:");
        A()[B()] += C();
        // ABC

        WriteLine("\nExplicit Assignment:");
        A()[B()] = A()[B()] + C();
        // ABABC
    }
}
```

Comment: `a` is only evaluated once in both cases. I can't think of an operator where they are not *exactly* (not just roughly) equivalent.

Comment: In the OP's example, the indexer would be evaluated twice, no? I must admit I am not too familiar with C♯. I know that the difference *can* be observed in Ruby, with which I am more familiar, by creating attribute writers / readers (think "property" in C♯) or indexers with side-effects.

Comment: There would be one read and one write in both cases. Overloading the indexer may prevent the operation from being atomic - but that would be true regardless of whether one uses `a ^= b` or `a = a ^ b`

Comment: Hmm. Then why did the C♯ designers feel the need to not only specify that explicitly but then even elucidate on it in an entire paragraph:

Comment: "If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of `x`, the operation is evaluated as `x = x op y`, except that `x` is **evaluated only once**. Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the return type of the selected operator is explicitly convertible to the type of `x`, and if `y` is implicitly convertible to the type of `x` or the operator is a shift operator, then the operation is evaluated as `x = (T)(x op y)`, where `T` is the type of `x`, except that `x` is **evaluated only once**."

Comment: "The term "**evaluated only once**" means that in the evaluation of `x op y`, the results of any constituent expressions of `x` are temporarily saved and then reused when performing the assignment to `x`. For example, in the assignment `A()[B()] += C()`, where `A` is a method returning `int[]`, and `B` and `C` are methods returning `int`, the methods are invoked **only once**, in the order `A`, `B`, `C`."

Comment: That applies to working with `dynamic` typing - in that the member resolution is only evaluated once. I wasn't aware of that behaviour when using dynamic; you learn something new every day - so it is indeed true that the operators *are* only roughly equivalent as you wrote!:)

Comment: I am actually reading that differently. To me, the first paragraph sounds like it stands alone, and specifies when binding happens and what the return type is in case the left-hand-side expression is `dynamic`. It says: "the resolution described below will take place at run-time based on the run-time type", which to me indicates that anything below that paragraph will happen regardless of whether the type is `dynamic` or not, just at different times. I coded up the example from that section, and it seems to validate my interpretation: https://repl.it/GfXO/0

Comment: In the compound assignment case, the evaluation order is A, B, C, like the spec says, but in the expanded, explicit case, it is A, B, A, B, C.